# Auto width on sliding hover link animation

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, css-animations

As you can see in my code (link below), I have a link animation which slides from left to right. How do I make the width of the underline the same width as the link "text", without making the width of the underline fixed?

https://jsfiddle.net/erikos93/rkqst9s5/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="aboutlinks">Facebook</a>
<a href="#" class="aboutlinks">LinkedIn</a>
<a href="#" class="aboutlinks">Instagram</a>

<a href="#" class="aboutlinks">This is just some random text.</a>
```

CSS:

```
.aboutlinks {
  color: #171717;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.aboutlinks:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #171717;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.aboutlinks:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Thanks beforehand!

//E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display: inline-block` to each link and after each link place `<br />`: https://jsfiddle.net/rkqst9s5/1/.

Comment: Thank you! This got me mad. I knew it was some ridiculously easy fix!